# How to get only the email's which is been sent or received from a specific account in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am searching for a solution like if i have to search certain email from my mail box(in this case Gmail) which is sent to a Email ID or received from that Email Id . I got some answers here but what they are doing is they are getting all the email from the mail box and iterating all emails and matching it with if else conditions.
The other way is to do with getSortedMessages method but Gmail does not support sorting also.It keeps throwing Exception.

So any others answer is suggested or i have to go with the traditional way of fetching all the Emails and iterate and check one after another and store into a array variable and return it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using IMAP, use [Folder.search](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) with [RecipientStringTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/RecipientStringTerm.html) and [FromStringTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/FromStringTerm.html):

```
Message[] msgs = inbox.search(new OrTerm(
                 new SearchTerm[] {
                    new RecipientStringTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO, "user@example.com"),
                    new RecipientStringTerm(Message.RecipientType.CC, "user@example.com"),
                    new FromStringTerm("user@example.com")
                  }));
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about it. It seems Like it needs one more extra parameter as Recipient Type. I am not able to get it. @Bill Shannon

Comment: I am trying to work out a solution on basis of the solution given . but it seems it is taking a little more time.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?